# Centigrade Textile Java Look and Feel Components layout

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I am using Centigrade's Textile Look and Feel (as you can see in their IconBook example jar http://www.centigrade.de/en/products/cezanne-look-and-feel-engine/launch). But there are following issues:
1. Buttons on all JOptionPane dialogs are very small, textfields are OK.
2. Combo box is trimmed so that the side arrow is not visible.
3. Menu is not displayed when JFrame is maximized.
4. JFileChooser also has very small OK and cancel buttons and combobox is trimmed.
Other Look and Feels are working fine. Please suggest what to do ?

Comment: this L&F (isn't free) has official support, post your request there

Comment: @shail Pandey you should ask to a particular product forum or tech support.